# How to show particular option of dropdownlist on page load using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am working in asp.net and code behind is C#. I have a dropdownlist in which I have given 3 options. "Age", "Gender" & "Status". Now I want that on every page load "Age" option should come on top of the list. When I choose "Gender" and clicks button on the next page load it remains "Gender" in the list. I want "Age" to come on the top. What line of code should I write in Page_Load() event?

Comment: `YourDropDownlist.SelectedValue = "Age";`?

Comment: I could pretend to be surprised, but I'm not. You didn't provide enough information for an answer that isn't just a guess. Try showing how you're setting up the dropdown for instance.

Comment: Does 'age' in your dropdown have a value associated with it?

Comment: OK. When I choose "Age" and provide age range and clicks on button, all the users with that range comes in a gridview on the bottom of dropdownlist. If I choose "Gender", all the user with the provided gender come in gridview. On the selection of "Gender" and after fetching records correspondent to "Gender" I want "Age" to come on the top of the list which is not coming. It shows previously selected option

Comment: yes. 'age','gender','status' have values 1,2,3 respectively

Comment: Not sure I fully understand but YourDropDownList.ClearSelection(); will clear it on pageload.

Comment: Also try YourDropDownlist.SelectedValue = "1";

Comment: CLearSelection() worked. Thank you @FullTimeSkeleton

Comment: But instead of page load i had to place ClearSelection() in button click

Comment: Make sure it's not losing you the selected value. if it is, try the second suggestion on page load.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Page_Load` event simply add `dropdown.SelectedValue = "Age";`

Make sure this occurs outside of the `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` statement if you have one.

Comment: according to your comments above `dropdown.SelectedValue = "1";` would have also worked for you.